# How to use negation "?!" in grep reg exp

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I want to find all malloc functions which doesnt contain sizeof() inside the argument. So i made regular expression - `malloc\((?!.*sizeof\().*\);`

The problem is that it works at reg exp online tolls but not when i try to use it in grep.

Example

```
cat file | grep "malloc\((?!.*sizeof\().*\);"
```

ANSWER:

```
bash: !.sizeof\: event not found
```

Any ideas ? Maybe "?!" doesnt work in grep reg exps" ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with grep or regexes. The error comes from bash. grep doesn't even run.

Comment: The `!` will get expanded by [*history expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html#Event-Designators)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grep default engine follows BRE syntax hence using a negative lookahead `(?!...)` is meaningless and may result an unwanted behavior. Set `-P` (:--perl-regexp) to be able to use it:

```
cat file | grep -P 'malloc\((?!.*sizeof\().*\);'
```

Comment: You should also point out that the history expansion (which is causing the error seen by the OP) is suppressed by the use of single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: Thanks  a  lot, that what i wanted to know :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk '/malloc/ && !/sizeof/' file
```

If you need to use grep, let's say for a homework, you need to use `grep` twice:

```
grep malloc file | grep -v sizeof
```

`-v` reverts the match, meaning grep will output lines which does not match the pattern.

---

You said:

> The problem is that it works at reg exp online tools but not when I try to use it in grep.

It looks like your online tools are not using [POSIX regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html) as grep. Please refer to the POSIX documenation (or read `man grep`)

Comment: I need to use grep, that is the problem otherwise i would do that

Comment: Use grep twice: `grep malloc file | grep -v sizeof`

Comment: @anticol Why do you need to use grep?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `"..."`. Bash evaluates some of its own constructs inside `"..."`, like `$PWD` or `` `pwd` `` or `!$`.

Check `man bash` for `!` expressions. You can use `\` to stop bash from trying to evaluate and fail what starts at `! ...` passing `!` through to grep.

Comment: Your regexp looks like a full perl (pcre) regex. Grep won't understand it; without trying it, I bet egrep won't either